# What value is alpha (as bit-shift represented)?

Tags: image-processing

If...

```
r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
b = rgb & 0xFF;
```

...then how is alpha determined in kind?  I.e.,...

```
a = rgb...
```

I'm using PHP GD and see no ready way to determine the alpha of an individual pixel.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is no standard, you'll have to look at the API for whatever is generating the pixel values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a 32-bit colorspace:

`a = (rgb >> 24) & 0xFF;`

Answer (score 2):

The format is typically ARGB, meaning the alpha channel is in the first 8 bits of the data, so to use your example, it would be:

```
a = (argb >> 24) & 0xFF;
r = (argb >> 16) & 0xFF;
g = (argb >> 8)  & 0xFF;
b = argb         & 0xFF;
```

Comment: Thank you.  Look these are equally valuable answers to me so I have to give the green check to the older, first incoming response.  I didn't know the alpha was in the first 8 bits of the data, and I also didn't know that I was dealing with a 32-bit colorspace.

Comment: Hey, no worries.  It happens a lot, so you have every right to choose the first answer.